# proactive detection of fraud model in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, isolation-forest

Detecting the fraud in the given dataset

I am currently working on proactive detection of fraud using Isolation forest in Jupyter notebook. I am finding it difficult to train the Isolation Forest Model. I am getting a valueerror: could not convert string to float: 'CASH_IN
This is my code:

```
model = IsolationForest(contamination=0.01, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train)
```

'

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. There's way too little info to give an answer. Additionally, search for the error you get online.